# How can I add an image immediately to the right of the text in a FrameLayout wrapper, which holds one of two dynamically sized TextViews?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a FrameLayout which is a wrapper for a TextView. The TextView can be either one of two TextView objects with dynamically modified text. I would like to add an image immediately to the right of the text contained in the FrameLayout. I have tried two things:

I set up the FrameLayout inside a RelativeLayout. I added an ImageView:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<!-- Two TextViews Here -->
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/my_frame_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  ...
/>
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_frame_layout"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This worked the first time the layout was loaded. However, when the text contained in the FrameLayout changed, the image stayed at its originally calculated position, rather than recalculating to stay to the right of the TextView.

So I tried making it a drawable and setting it in code. I fetched the TextView held in the FrameLayout, and called:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,myDrawable,0)
```

This worked well, except that the drawable is always to the furthest right point of the FrameLayout, despite the TextView being only half full. I want the image to be immediately to the right of the text.

Does anyone have any other suggestions I could try to make this happen?

Comment: did you try calling requestLayout() on the RelativeLayout after you changed the text?

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the ImageView in an additional LinearLayout, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/my_image_wrapper"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_toRightOf="my_frame_layout"
  android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
  >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Unlike the ImageView alone, the LinearLayout is redrawn when the text changes size, so this worked for me.